# Left join for cell arrays in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, left-join, cell-array

I've 2 **cell** arrays in MATLAB, for example:

```
A= {jim,4,paul,5 ,sean ,5,rose, 1}
```

and the second:

```
B= {jim, paul, george, bill, sean ,rose}
```

I want to make an SQL left join so I'll have all the values from B and their match from A. If they don't appear in A so it will be '0'. means:

```
C= {jim, 4, paul, 5, george, 0, bill, 0, sean, 5, rose, 1}
```

didn't find any relevant function for help. 
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Approach #1

```
%// Inputs
A= {'paul',5 ,'sean' ,5,'rose', 1,'jim',4}
B= {'jim', 'paul', 'george', 'bill', 'sean' ,'rose'}

%// Reshape A to extract the names and the numerals separately later on
Ar = reshape(A,2,[]);

%// Account for unsorted A with respect to B
[sAr,idx] = sort(Ar(1,:))
Ar = [sAr ; Ar(2,idx)]

%// Detect the presence of A's in B's  and find the corresponding indices 
[detect,pos] = ismember(B,Ar(1,:))

%// Setup the numerals for the output as row2
row2 = num2cell(zeros(1,numel(B)));
row2(detect) = Ar(2,pos(detect)); %//extracting names and numerals here

%// Append numerals as a new row into B and reshape as 1D cell array
out = reshape([B;row2],1,[])
```

Code run -

```
A = 
    'paul'    [5]    'sean'    [5]    'rose'    [1]    'jim'    [4]
B = 
    'jim'    'paul'    'george'    'bill'    'sean'    'rose'
out = 
    'jim'    [4]    'paul'    [5]    'george'    [0]    'bill'    [0]    'sean'    [5]    'rose'    [1]
```

### Approach #2

If you want to work with the numerals in the cell arrays as strings, you can use this modified version -

```
%// Inputs [Please edit these to your actual inputs]
A= {'paul',5 ,'sean' ,5,'rose', 1,'jim',4};
B= {'jim', 'paul', 'george', 'bill', 'sean' ,'rose'}

%// Convert the numerals into string format for A
A = cellfun(@(x) num2str(x),A,'Uni',0)

%// Reshape A to extract the names and the numerals separately later on
Ar = reshape(A,2,[]);

%// Account for unsorted A with respect to B
[sAr,idx] = sort(Ar(1,:));
Ar = [sAr ; Ar(2,idx)];

%// Detect the presence of A's in B's  and find the corresponding indices 
[detect,pos] = ismember(B,Ar(1,:));

%// Setup the numerals for the output as row2
row2 = num2cell(zeros(1,numel(B)));
row2 = cellfun(@(x) num2str(x),row2,'Uni',0); %// Convert to string formats
row2(detect) = Ar(2,pos(detect)); %//extracting names and numerals here

%// Append numerals as a new row into B and reshape as 1D cell array
out = reshape([B;row2],1,[])
```

Code run -

```
B = 
    'jim'    'paul'    'george'    'bill'    'sean'    'rose'
A = 
    'paul'    '5'    'sean'    '5'    'rose'    '1'    'jim'    '4'
out = 
    'jim'    '4'    'paul'    '5'    'george'    '0'    'bill'    '0'    'sean'    '5'    'rose'    '1'
```

Comment: I already tried the "ismember" function, but I got the error: **'Error using cell/ismember>cellismemberR2012a (line 192)
Input A of class cell and input B of class cell must be cell arrays of strings, unless one is a string.

Error in cell/ismember (line 56)
    [varargout{1:max(1,nargout)}] = cellismemberR2012a(A,B);** I think its because its a cell array of double and string.

Comment: @Yaeli778 Can you check if `Ar(1,:)` contains any numerals?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by that, but my array is a cell array of two dimensions.

Comment: @Yaeli778 Check out Approach #2?

Comment: @Yaeli778 What's the output of `size(A)` and `size(B)`? Also, if you just copy and paste the codes from here (that is you use the inputs listed in the solution), does it still throw the same error?

Comment: If I copy paste the code from here I don't have any error. When I run my code, with my arrays, I get the error.`size(Acq)
ans =        7853           2 size(input3)

ans =

       14575           1`

Comment: @Yaeli778 So your `A` seems to have 2 columns, right? Could you edit your question with a sample A that has the 2-column format?

Comment: So, I was stupid, and my dimensions sizes were opposite... anyway, now I got some results but they were wrong. seems like my 2 arrays are not sorted in the same way... what can I do then? Thanks for your help

Comment: I think I have managed that. I sorted both and now its fine. You can add to your answer that both should be in the same order. Thanks!!

Comment: I think its better to leave it like before, and add a comment that they should be in the same order... but its your decision :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67016/discussion-between-yaeli778-and-divakar).

Comment: @Yaeli778 Well I edited the codes to make it work with out-of-order A and B. If you look at the edited `Inputs`, they are not in order. Could you check the codes again?

Comment: oh, I understood. that's seems fine to me. just one more (last) request.. Can you send me #approach1 code before adding the sort issue? because my MATLAB was crushed and I want to check something.

Comment: @Yaeli778 All those revisions are available [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27490234/revisions).