# Left Join tables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, join, left-join

I tried to find something relevant but to no avail, except this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490039/left-join-for-cell-arrays-in-matlab) which I can't say it was helpful.

I have two tables A and B:
A has dimensions 5x5 and non unique values in the `LastName`

```
LastName = {'Smith';'Johnson';'Williams';'Smith';'Williams'};
YearNow= [2010;2010;2010;2010;2010];
Height = [71;69;64;67;64];
Weight = [176;163;131;133;119];
BloodPressure = [124; 109; 125; 117; 122];
A = table(LastName,YearNow,Height,Weight,BloodPressure);
```

and B has dimensions 3x2 and unique values in `LastName`

```
LastName = {'Smith';'Johnson';'Williams'};
YearBorn= [1950;1975;1965];
B = table(LastName,YearBorn);
```

I want to create a new column on Table A that will contain their age after I subtract for each A.YearNow the B.YearBorn, so the last column will have the form

```
A.Age = [60,35,45,60,45];
```

When I try to use `[detect,pos] = ismember(A,B(:,1));` I get an error:

> A and B must contain the same variables.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `ismember`, which can be quite error-prone as you have to put things in the right order, you could also use Matlab's `outerjoin` instead:

```
A = outerjoin(A,B,'Type','Left','MergeKeys',true);
A.Age = A.YearNow - A.YearBorn;
```

Note that `outerjoin` modifies the ordering. See the [official Matlab documentation](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/outerjoin.html) for all the input arguments.

An additional advantage of `outerjoin` over `ismember` is that in case not all LastNames in table A exist in table B, you will have to pre-allocate output with `ismember`, and use the first output argument as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract the `LastName` columns and pass them to [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html). Then you can use the index vector it returns to compute the `Age` column as follows:

```
[~, index] = ismember(A.LastName, B.LastName);
A.Age = A.YearNow-B.YearBorn(index);
```